# How can I fix these two for loops to allow modification of the vector content?

Tags: for-loop, rust, mutable, borrowing

I'm trying to make a loop over the matrix made using a `Vec<f64>` inside a Vec, and then alter its elements one by one.

I cannot seem to make it work; I'm still too confused about the syntax...

```
extern crate rand;

use std::ptr;
use std::mem;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut v: Vec<Vec<f64>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(vec![0f64; 35]);
    v.push(vec![0f64; 35]);
    v.push(vec![0f64; 35]);
    v.push(vec![0f64; 35]);

    let len = v.len();
    for &el in &v {
        for q in &mut el {
            q = rng.gen::<f64>();
            println!("{}", q);
        }
        println!("{:?}", el);
    }
    println!("float: {}", rng.gen::<f64>());
    //println!("vec: {:?}, len: {}",v,len);
}
```

The compiler says this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
19 |             q = rng.gen::<f64>();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &mut f64, found f64
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut f64`
              found type `f64`
   = help: try with `&mut rng.gen::<f64>()`
```

I tried following the compiler hints, various combinations of `mut &` and `.iter()` or `.iter_mut()`, but none of them worked. After some frustration, I noticed that my search for a solution had become a Monte Carlo algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the error messages — they are a huge benefit of a statically typed language, but it does require you to actually *look* at them.

```
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
19 |             q = rng.gen::<f64>();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &mut f64, found f64
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut f64`
              found type `f64`
   = help: try with `&mut rng.gen::<f64>()`
```

Unfortunately, the "help" here isn't the right path, but it's just a guess from the compiler.

You are attempting to create a random value of type `f64` and assign it to a variable that holds a `&mut f64`. These are different types, so you get an error.

You need to dereference the variable to store into it:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let mut v = vec![
        vec![0f64; 35],
        vec![0f64; 35],
        vec![0f64; 35],
        vec![0f64; 35],
    ];

    for el in &mut v {
        for q in el {
            *q = rng.gen::<f64>();
        }   
    }

    println!("vec: {:?}", v);
}
```

---

I'd probably not zero-initialize anything though, and write it as

```
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

let v: Vec<Vec<f64>> = (0..4)
    .map(|_| (0..35).map(|_| rng.gen()).collect())
    .collect();

println!("vec: {:?}", v);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both for restructuring the code and for explaining the problem! I'll accept as soon as i can.
And thank you for the functional programming way of creating the vec! i would give two +1 if i could!